# Do "embedding" and "injective homomorphism" mean the same thing?

Tags: definition

On page 6 of *A Shorter Model Theory*, it says

> For example if $G$ and $H$ are groups and $f : G \to H$ is a
>   homomorphism, then (2.1) says that $f(1^G)=1^H$ and $f(a^{(-1)^{G}}) =
> > f(a)^{(-1)^{H}}$. This is exactly the usual definition of homomorphism
>   between groups. Clause (2.2) adds nothing in this case since there are
>   no relation symbols in the signature. For the same reason (2.4) is
>   vacuous for groups. *So a homomorphism between groups is an embedding
>   if and only if it is an injective homomorphism.*

Emphasis added.

Hodges always bolds terms when providing a definition **like this**, which I think means that *embedding* and *injective homomorphism* refer to separately-defined notions that happen to line up in this specific case.

Intuitively I think of an *embedding* and an *injective homomorphism* as the same thing, not even differing intensionally, but I think this intuition is wrong.

How do *embedding* and *injective homomorphism* differ in meaning? Is there a good example that demonstrates this?

Comment: The question is what an *embedding* is, since injective group homomorphism is perfectly clear. The answer depends on the context, e.g., see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1752710/what-exactly-is-an-embedding-in-differential-geometry) (and now also Matt's answer).

Comment: As, it turns out _embedding_ is defined on the previous page as an injective homomorphism where $\vec{a} \in R^A \iff f(\vec{a}) \in R^B$ instead of the weaker condition $\vec{a} \in R^A \implies f(\vec{a}) \in R^B$ where $R$ is an arbitrary predicate symbol in our signature and $R^A$ refers to the particular predicate $R$ in the structure $A$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For groups they are the same thing. For topological spaces, they are not. There can be an injective continuous map $f:X\to Y$ where the image $f(X) $ is not homeomorphic to $X$. A quick example is $X=[0, 2\pi)$, $Y=S^1$, $f(x) =e^{ix} $.

Comment: @Gregory An injective homomorphism has a left inverse. However, the left inverse need not be a homomorphism (that's what happens in my example, it's not continuous). You could require that the left inverse be a homomorphism.

Comment: I deleted my earlier comment because I saw that I missed the answer on the previous page of the book. It said, roughly, "is there a way to define an embedding in general as `an injective homomorphism that additionally satisfies the property [...]`".

Answer (score 2):

Here is a finite example involving partial orders. Intuitively, if we take a partial order that is not a linear order and linearize it, the $\le$ relation now has *extra pairs of elements in it that were not there originally.*

Let $\left(*\right)^W$ denote the set of pairs inhabiting the $*$ relation in $W$. $*$ itself may be thought of as an abstract predicate or as a set of pairs, $\left(*\right)^W$ is always a set of pairs.

Let's define a single non-logical binary predicate $\le \mathop{:} \mathcal{D} \times \mathcal{D} \to \left\{ \top, \bot \right\} $ , with $\mathcal{D}$ being the domain of the model.

$\le$ can also be thought of as a set of pairs $P\left( \mathcal{D} \times \mathcal{D} \right)$ .

The theory of partial orders consists the following laws:

$$ a \le a \tag{1a}$$
$$ a \le b \land b \le c \implies a \le c \tag{1b} $$

Let's define two partial orders on 3 elements, $A$ and $B$ . Let the three elements be $\mathcal{D} = \left\{ g, h, k \right\}$ .

```
        A                   B


        g                   g
       / \                   \
      /   \                   h
     h     k                   \
                                k
```

Let $f : \left\{ g, h, k \right\} \to \left\{ g, h, k \right\} = \text{id} $ denote a function from the domain of $A$ to the domain of $B$. I will show that $f$ is an injective homomorphism and that $f$ is not an embedding.

Here (3a-3b) are the elements of $\left(\le\right)^A$ and $\left(\le\right)^B$ .

Note that

$$\left(=\right)^A = \left(=\right)^B \tag{2} $$

Examining $\left(\le\right)$ specifically.

$$ \left\{ \left(g,h\right), \left(g,k\right) \right\} \cup \left(=\right)^A = \left(\le\right)^A \tag{3a} $$
$$ \left\{ \left(g,h\right), \left(g,k\right), \left(h,k\right) \right\} \cup \left(=\right)^B = \left(\le\right)^B \tag{3b} $$

From (2) and (3a-3b) it is clear that $\left(\le\right)^A \subsetneq \left(\le\right)^B$, which means that $f$ is a homomorphism and a non-embedding. $f$ is injective because the graph of $f$ is the identity function, which is a bijection.

Answer (score -1):

Embedding is a term used for the underlying set of space, for instance we may embed the set of integers $\mathbb{Z}$ by a list of distinct points $\{x_n\}\in\mathbb{R}$. Homomorphism is used for maps that preserve addition and multiplication. For instance we only have two homomorphism $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, i.e. zero map and identity map. But we can construct many embeddings $g: \mathbb{Z}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ by choosing different lists $\{x_n\}$